# Gradle failed to restore: Unable to find method 'org.gradle.api.file.ProjectLayout.directoryProperty

Tags: android, gradle

I was loading an Android project that downloaded from Github, the project look fairly recent and nothing weird that I can find. But when I open it, it failed to build with the following error:

> Unable to find method
> 'org.gradle.api.file.ProjectLayout.directoryProperty(Lorg/gradle/api/provider/Provider;)Lorg/gradle/api/file/DirectoryProperty;'.
> Possible causes for this unexpected error include: Gradle's dependency
> cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection
> timeout.) Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)
>
> The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping
> all Gradle daemons may solve this problem. Stop Gradle build processes
> (requires restart)
>
> Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible
> with the other plugins in the project or the version of Gradle
> requested by the project.
>
> In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the
> IDE and then killing all Java processes.

Other android projects that were created on my machine works fine.
What can be the issue?

Comment: check `gradle-wrapper.properties` and change it to be like the same path other projects use.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

The issue was that I upgraded to Android Studio v4, and seem like the download project was created using Android Studio v3.
After go to

> File/ Project Structure.../

And change the `Android Gradle Plugin Version` from `3.3.1` to `4.0.1` and now project loaded fine.
Not sure why Android Studio v4 is not backward compatible with Gradle version 3.
[image]

Comment: It works!! Thank you, you saved my day. I tried with gradle-6.6.1-all.zip https://services.gradle.org/distributions/ but I'm sure with 6.1.1 should be ok as well :)

Comment: This is solution! Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

To determine plugin version and required Gradle version, developers can refer the compatibility matrix provided in Android documentation from [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin).

| Plugin version | Required Gradle version |
| --- | --- |
| 1.0.0 - 1.1.3 | 2.2.1 - 2.3 |
| 1.2.0 - 1.3.1 | 2.2.1 - 2.9 |
| 1.5.0 | 2.2.1 - 2.13 |
| 2.0.0 - 2.1.2 | 2.10 - 2.13 |
| 2.1.3 - 2.2.3 | 2.14.1 - 3.5 |
| 2.3.0+ | 3.3+ |

Answer (score 2):

I had to change the distributionUrl in the gradle-wrapper.properties to

distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.1.1-all.zip

to get the build running again.